# Can I configure settings in UWP app desktop scanner?

Tags: .net, uwp, resolution, scanning

I have had good success in getting input from a flatbed scanner in my UWP app

```
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.Scanners;

ImageScanner myScanner = await ImageScanner.FromIdAsync(deviceId);
var result = await myScanner.ScanFilesToFolderAsync(ImageScannerScanSource.Default, folder);
```

and even make use of the auto configured scan profile

```
if (myScanner.IsScanSourceSupported(ImageScannerScanSource.AutoConfigured))
{
    ...
    // Scan API call to start scanning with Auto-Configured settings. 
    var result = await myScanner.ScanFilesToFolderAsync(
        ImageScannerScanSource.AutoConfigured, folder).AsTask(cancellationToken.Token, progress);
    ...
}
```

but is there any way that I can control the configuration, get a lower resolution or just B&W? All of the format options appear to be read only properties. I have tried to make an external scanner profile in Win10 but it isn't picked up (even when it is the default). The API appears to be aware of the scanner supported settings because the ScanToStream equivalent call reads in lowest possible resolution as a preview.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way that I can control the configuration, get a lower resolution or just B&W

Sure, please check [`ImageScanner.FlatbedConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.scanners.imagescanner.flatbedconfiguration.aspx) property

The [`ImageScannerFlatbedConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.scanners.imagescannerflatbedconfiguration.aspx) class includes several writable properties, for example: [DesiredResolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.scanners.imagescannerflatbedconfiguration.desiredresolution.aspx) and [ColorMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.scanners.imagescannerflatbedconfiguration.colormode.aspx)

A sample to set the scan file format to PNG and adjust the desired resolution:

```
if (scanner.IsScanSourceSupported(ImageScannerScanSource.Flatbed))
{

// Set the scan file format to PNG, if available
    if (scanner.FlatbedConfiguration != null)
    {
        if (scanner.FlatbedConfiguration.IsFormatSupported(ImageScannerFormat.Png))
        {
            scanner.FlatbedConfiguration.Format = ImageScannerFormat.Png;
        }

        scanner.FlatbedConfiguration.DesiredResolution = new ImageScannerResolution { DpiX = 200, DpiY = 200 };
    }

    this._cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var scanTask = scanner.ScanFilesToFolderAsync(ImageScannerScanSource.Flatbed, Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
    scanTask.Progress = (info, progressInfo) => Debug.WriteLine("Page {0}", progressInfo);

    var scanResults = await scanTask.AsTask(this._cancellationToken.Token);
}
```

Reference: [[WinRT] How to scan documents](http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2015/05/winrt-how-to-scan-documents-in-a-windows-8-1-application/)